# bitcoin-cli failed with error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword

Tags: json-rpc, bitcoin-cli, authentication

When I run this command

```
bitcoind -testnet -printtoconsole -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=123456
```

After bitcoind is up. I run this on the same Ubuntu 17.10

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=123456 getbalance
```

I get this result:
error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)
The second day I tried exactly the same way. I get the correct result. It is really weird.

I try to put these two lines in /home/user/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf

```
rpcuser=123456
rpcpassword=123456
```

And I run this command

```
bitcoind -testnet -printtoconsole -conf=/home/gogogo237/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
```

And this

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=1234564 getbalance
```

notice that I intentionally changed -rpcpassword to a wrong password. But I still can get a correct result. 
This is really unpredictable and obviously a mistake. Anyone can explain this error? Thanks!

Comment: interesting, but for sure not the default behavious. I am normally on OpenSuSE. I have self compiled and downloaded full clients. Please provide some more info: did you use bitcoin core from website? Self compiled? apt-get? Did you check download files (hash)? 
I think I have a fresh Ubuntu virtual machine, where I could try to install the one you where using...

Comment: Self compiled from the newest source code.

Comment: similiar discussion here, as bitcoin15 is not yet released: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=2172765.0. You downloaded from https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin?

Comment: just downloaded from github, and couldn't compile, cause autoconf throws already some errors. And for sure ./configure as well. Damn, wanting to help, and now need help myself ...

Comment: To avoid others doing same error (RTFM correctly, not in a rush): autogen.sh, not autoconf !! Now it's compiling. Update to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re-compiled on an Ubuntu system, fresh from github.com:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-ae 4.10.0-19-generic

$ bitcoind -version
Bitcoin Core Daemon version v0.15.99.0-g96ac26e5662

$ bitcoind -testnet -printtoconsole -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=123456

$ bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=123456 getaccountaddress "myaccount"
n2r1aQiA37LLgy4qWjuLHXqA9ZhtcX4KG6

$ bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=123456 getbalance
0.00000000
```

and with wrong password:

```
$ bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=1234564 getbalance
error: incorrect rpcuser or rpcpassword (authorization failed)
```

so s.th. is wrong with the sources? Or with Ubuntu setup. What kernel do you have (uname -a) ?

Comment: just compiled the newest version. Here is my command
$ bitcoind -testnet -printtoconsole -rpcuser=123456 -rpcpassword=123456
bitcoin-cli -testnet getbalance
It just work! Wierd.

Answer (score -1):

In case you changed your `/etc/systemd/system/bitcoind.service` make sure you run

```
 sudo systemctl stop bitcoind
 sudo systemctl daemon-reload
 sudo systemctl start bitcoind
```

to apply the changes.

The error from the question could (and did in my case) arise because I did not use `daemon-reload` to load the new config.

Comment: While this advice may be useful, the question doesn't ask anything about systemd or with changing systemd service files.

Comment: The error from the question could (and did in my case) arise because I did not use `daemon-reload` to load the new config. Since this solved my problem - which was the same as OPs -  I thought it would be a good thing to know.